# SQL Server : Where NULL columns from dynamic list

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm writing a query against a table **A** where I want to find out if a row in table **A** has fields that are **null**. The thing is that these fields are dynamic and are found in another table **B**.

Normally you would write,

Table **A** ....

```
 WHERE A.myField1 IS NOT NULL AND A.myField2 IS NOT NULL
```

But in this case I want to do

table **A** ....

```
WHERE (some columns in table **A** specified in table **B**) IS NOT NULL
```

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Could you provide sample data and expected results?

Comment: You can use [dynamic SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to construct and execute your query.

Comment: You can create a procedure to generate the query as a string, then evaluate it.

Comment: It sounds like you simply need to `JOIN` your tables but as it reads, it's really unclear what you are after. Sample data and expected output would help. [See this on how to write the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). The guy who wrote that is [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) who has the most reputation on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you may try to generate dynamic SQL statement and execute this statement:

```
-- Tables
CREATE TABLE #TableA (
    MyField1 int,
    MyField2 int,
    MyField3 int,
    MyField4 int,
    MyField5 int,
    MyField6 int
)
CREATE TABLE #TableB (
    FieldName nvarchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO #TableB 
    (FieldName)
VALUES
    ('MyField1'),
    ('MyField2'),
    ('MyField3')

-- Declarations
DECLARE 
    @stm nvarchar(max),
    @err int

-- Statement generation
SET @stm = N''
SELECT @stm = @stm +
        N'AND (' +
        [FieldName] +
        N' IS NOT NULL) '
FROM #TableB
SET @stm = 
    N'SELECT * FROM #TableA WHERE ' +
    STUFF(@stm, 1, 4, N'')

-- Execution
PRINT @stm
EXEC @err = sp_executesql @stm
IF @err = 0 
    PRINT 'OK'
ELSE 
    PRINT 'Error'
```

Generated statement:

```
SELECT * 
FROM #TableA 
WHERE (MyField1 IS NOT NULL) AND (MyField2 IS NOT NULL) AND (MyField3 IS NOT NULL)
```